# How to plot the frequency of an event over a timeseries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a data frame with dates and a quality dummy (0 or 1):

```
      unixTimestamp         date     quality
 0       1370131200   06 2, 2013           1
 1       1290643200  11 25, 2010           1
 2       1283990400   09 9, 2010           1
 3       1290556800  11 24, 2010           1
 4       1317254400  09 29, 2011           1
 5       1388707200   01 3, 2014           1
 6       1398556800  04 27, 2014           1
 7       1399161600   05 4, 2014           0
 8       1405036800  07 11, 2014           1
 9       1390176000  01 20, 2014           1
 10      1397606400  04 16, 2014           1
```

What I want to do: plot the frequency of yes (1) in `quality` over time.

What I have tried: plot a histogram like this:

```
plt.hist(x=df.loc[df['quality'] == 1].unixTimestamp, bins=78)
plt.show()
```

I have chosen 78 because the latest date where `quality` equal 1 is at  1405123200 and the earliest is 1203379200. This translates to 07/12/2014 and 02/19/2008, respectively. The difference between the two is 78 months.
The resulting output is quite messy:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to plot this trend on a scatter plot? I am working with `unixTimestamp` only. Suggestions on a better way to deal with time series data are very welcome.

Also, this was run on 170 rows of the `df`. The actual data has ~10M rows. Can someone also suggest the best way to represent the data? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pls copy and paste the sample data instead of pasting it as image. That will be a real help.

Comment: @JimTodd added. Thank you! The raw dataset is here, http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/ but it would be irrelevant to this problem. You may find it handy for yourself though. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are looking to group your observations by date and then the number of rows, within each period (day, month, ...) that have quality equal to one.

That job is cut out for the `.groupby` method in pandas. Before we do the grouping, let's make sure that the dates are also recognised by python.

```
import pandas as pd

df['alt_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['unixTimestamp'], unit='s')
daily_quality = df.groupby('alt_date')['quality'].sum()
```

Now, you can plot the result using `pd.DataFrame.plot()`, which uses matplotlib to easily draw plots from pandas dataframes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

daily_quality.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

If you are looking to group your date by month instead, you can use `pd.Grouper()`, which works like this:

```
monthly_quality = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='alt_date', freq='M'))['quality']
                    .sum()
                    .fillna(0)   # in case you have missing months

monthly_quality.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do make the bars per months?, like I had tried in the histogram?

Comment: @Vibhu i updated the answer for the case of monthly grouping

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer for this question. Just erase the extra period before the hashtag comment. It is causing an error. Thank you and wishing you a happy new year!